How to retrieve join-table extra data in a many-to-many relationship using Supabase?
For a many-to-many relationship between two tables, I have a 3rd join-table that contains extra data.
lists <> lists_items_rel <> items
The lists_items_rel join-table contains the two IDs to join the two tables and an additionnal column added_by.

list_id: uint8
item_id: uint8
added_by: uuid

Querying the database using the documentation with this code :
    const { data, error } = await this.supabaseService.getClient()
      .from('lists')
      .select('id, items(*)')
      .eq('id', listId);

returns all the correct data but without the added_by column :
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "apple",
        "unit": "pieces",
        "quantity": 2,
        "created_at": "2024-08-11T15:59:25.294356+00:00",
        "created_by": "dba7e125-61f8-4bf6-bc25-f6fe6d3b92b0"
        // "added_by": "dba7e125-61f8-4bf6-bc25-f6fe6d3b92b0" <- this is missing
    }
]

What can I add to this code to also include the additional data in the column lists_items_rel.added_by?
